# Build Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR) from scratch

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-models, speech-recognition

I want to build a Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR) engine for myself, but I've no idea from where to start.

I've read that most ASR's are build upon Hidden Markov Models, but also I've read that HMM is limited somehow and a better approach is to build a ASR upon Machine Learning features.

Overall I am confused.

Can someone recommend me books on topics from which I can start?

Thanks (:

Comment: 1. This question is too broad and you're probably better off spending more time self-studying standard resources on speech recognition.  There's *lots* written about it out there, so if you've been having trouble finding resources, you haven't done enough searching.  2. Book recommendations are generally off-topic for this site.  See http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20/755 and http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/874/755.

Comment: What is an ASR for you? HMM or equvalent techniques are only the very beginning of a long processing chain. How far do you want it to go?

Comment: I want to build a simple ASR which recognizes only few words ("yes" and "no" for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to build a Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR) engine for myself, but I've no idea from where to start.

Start with trying existing open source speech recognition system, learn how they work, play with them. Check http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net.

> I've read that most ASR's are build upon Hidden Markov Models, but also I've read that HMM is limited somehow and a better approach is to build a ASR upon Machine Learning features.

HMM which provide time variance is still a reasonable model for speech, most of the system use it in one form or another. Limitations of HMM exist, but you do not need to care about them on that level.

You can implement a basic speech recognition system without HMM. For example check

http://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/developing-an-isolated-word-recognition-system-in-matlab.html

That would be enough for "yes" and "no" discrimination. For any more serious use you will need HMM.

> Can someone recommend me books on topics from which I can start?

There are two good books on topic:

A basic guide to start:

[http://www.amazon.com/Spoken-Language-Processing-Algorithm-Development/dp/0130226165](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130226165)

A modern state of the art

[http://www.amazon.com/Automatic-Speech-Recognition-Communication-Technology/dp/1447157788/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1447157788)